# Jetbrains Rider - Universal Windows Platform SDK was not found

Tags: c#, rider

#### Instructions

I installed the **[Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/)** and wanted to create a **UWP application**. After the **solution** is created, **Jetbrains Rider** gives an error.

#### Error

> Universal Windows Platform SDK was not found: Please install UWP SDK
> via Visual Studio Build Tools, or specify a different MSBuild version
> in settings.

#### Settings of the Solution

[Screenshot of the settings from the Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHPb9.png)

#### Question

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: According to the Error message, you may need to install the redistributable MSBuild of JetBrain, have a look at this blog as well. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/13/introducing-jetbrains-redistributable-msbuild/

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem.